# HyperV VM fails to start, yet settings says it's running

Tags: hyper-v

I have a VM that has been running fine. I've changed noting in the host machine or the VM. When I try to start it I get the "Not enough memory in the system to start the virtual machine Fiona.

[image]

Now here's what's really screwy. I go to setting to try different memory settings - and I can't. It wants me to shut down the VM. But it is shut down (won't start).

[image]

How do I address this problem?

Comment: Free up memory.

Comment: @MichaelHampton How? The settings won't let me change the memory settings for the VM. And on the host machine I have nothing much running.

Comment: Define "nothing much". What is running? Why doesn't the machine have enough memory to unsuspend this VM?

Comment: @MichaelHampton That's what is weird here. There is nothing additional running on the host machine. I have been removing uneeded things that were running like Teams and OneDrive. Hasn't made a difference so far.

Comment: @MichaelHampton And after a second reboot - it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking to see if where you are storing the pagefile is out of space.

Comment: Good suggestion but the drive has 1/2 terrabyte free